# Search Print queues using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a quick string of code that allows me to search a specific print server and also its contents such as printers. What I want for it to do is once getting the printer information to be able to find a specific printer using the port name which in this case is an IP address not quite sure if is possible but I haven't found a command that lets me define a search using those values.

```
    Get-Printer -computerName "server01"|select-object -Property Name, PortName
```

**Name       PortName

Printer01 X.XX.XXX.X

Prnter02 X.XX.XX.XX**

is there a way to be able to find a printer using the Get-Printer commandlet and utilizing the port name to find the specific printer?

Comment: I commend to your attention the cmdlet [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I tried to use the Where-Object cmdlet just now and when running it returns with no output in the console

Answer (score 0):

I'm just explaining in more detail **@JeffZeitlin** very correct answer.

**Get-Printer** - The Get-Printer cmdlet retrieves a list of printers installed on a computer. You can also use Get-Printer to retrieve the properties of a single printer, and then use that information as input into other cmdlets.

**Get-Printer | Get-Member** - The Get-Member cmdlet gets the members, the properties and methods, of objects.

```
Get-Printer | get-member
```

**Get-Printer | Select-Object** - The Select-Object cmdlet selects specified properties of an object or set of objects. It can also select unique objects, a specified number of objects, or objects in a specified position in an array.

```
Get-Printer | select-object -Property Name, PortName
```

**Get-Printer | Select-Object | Where-Object** - The Where-Object cmdlet selects objects that have particular property values from the collection of objects that are passed to it. For example, you can use the Where-Object cmdlet to select files that were created after a certain date, events with a particular ID, or computers that use a particular version of Windows.

```
Get-Printer | select-object -Property Name, PortName | where PortName -eq "PORTPROMPT:"
```

**Get-Printer -ComputerName**

```
Get-Printer -ComputerName $env:Computername | select-object -Property Name, PortName | where PortName -eq "PORTPROMPT:"
```

**Scripting Example Get-Printer**

```
$server = "$env:Computername"
$printersportnames = Get-Printer -ComputerName $server | select-object -ExpandProperty PortName
#Write-Host $printersportnames

$results = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList # Empty Array

ForEach ($printerportname in $printersportnames) {
    $printerportname = $printerportname.ToString()
    #Write-Host $printerportname
    $output = Get-Printer -ComputerName $server | where-object {$_.PortName -eq $printerportname}
    
    $x = $output.Name
    $y = $output.PortName
    $z = $output.CommunicationStatus
    $a = $output.OperatingStatus
    
    $Object = New-Object PSObject   
    $Object | Add-Member -Name 'Name' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $x
    $Object | Add-Member -Name 'PortName' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $y
    $Object | Add-Member -Name 'CommStatus' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $z
    $Object | Add-Member -Name 'OperStatus' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $a
    
    $results += $object
    
}

$results
```